# Couldn't find type: v1.Deployment

Tags: deployment, kubernetes

I am following [this tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/).

My objective was to create a Deployment made with a custom container instead of the hello container.

I made this `my-custom-server-deployment.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-custom-server-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-custom
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-custom-server
          image: my-custom-server
          ports:
              containerPort: 3000
```

I tried to build it with `kubectl create -f my-custom-server-deployment.yaml` and i got:

```
error: error validating "my-custom-server-deployment.yaml": error validating data: couldn't find type: v1.Deployment; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --vali
date=false
```

When i add `--validate=false` i get:

```
 no matches for /, Kind=Deployment
```

I thought this was pretty straight forward. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add `kubectl version` please?

Comment: `kubectl api-versions |grep apps` will give you supported api version

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using `apiVersion: apps/v1beta1` instead. I believe Deployments is a still a beta feature.